# Command binding for button in ItemsControl in WPF NotifyIcon

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, itemssource, notifyicon

I'm using hardcodet's WPF NotifyIcon in my app, which is being implemented using MVVM Light. I'm trying to create a custom TrayPopup for the icon. In this popup I have an ItemsControl, whose ItemsSource is a list of objects "NumberList" in my ViewModel. For my DataTemplate I'm using a grid which display an property called "Id" of my source object, and a button. The button I'm trying to tie back to a RelayCommand in my ViewModel. I've done similar things with ItemsControls in the past by Binding using a RelativeSource to get the DataContext of the Window Ancestor. I tried a similar approach this time, but when I run the app, open the TrayPopup, and click the button nothing happens. My command is not fired in my ViewModel.

As a test I tried adding another button to my TrayPopup and binding its command to the same one in my ViewModel. That binding works fine, so it's not the command as far as I can tell.

Like I said, I've used this technique almost exactly in the past, just never before in a NotifyIcon. I've tried specifying the ElementName in the button Binding to the name of my Window, which didn't work. I've also tried changing the RelativeSource to the parent TaskbarIcon, also without success.

Here is an example implementation of what the NotifyIcon with the same problem:

```
<tb:TaskbarIcon PopupActivation="LeftOrRightClick">
        <tb:TaskbarIcon.TrayPopup>
            <Grid Background="White">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0">
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding NumberList, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Id, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                                    <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Test" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.TestCommand}"/> <!--This binding doesn't work!-->
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </ScrollViewer>

                <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Test2" Command="{Binding TestCommand}"/> <!--This works-->
            </Grid>
        </tb:TaskbarIcon.TrayPopup>
    </tb:TaskbarIcon>
```

I'm fairly confident everything in the ViewModel is correct as I have been using a previous version of this app that I wrote a while ago. So far I haven't run in to any problems other than this NotifyIcon. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After banging away at it for a while I found an answer to my problem. The StackPanel in my ItemsPanelTemplate had the DataContext which contained the command I wanted to bind my button to, my main ViewModel. By specifying a name for the StackPanel, I was able to set the ElementName of my button to its name, and then the binding worked. Not sure why this method worked with the StackPanel and not the main Window though.

Anyway, here's the updated code if anyone runs in to this same problem:

```
<tb:TaskbarIcon PopupActivation="LeftOrRightClick">
    <tb:TaskbarIcon.TrayPopup>
        <Grid Background="White">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding NumberList, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Id, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                                <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Test" Command="{Binding ElementName=trayMainStack, Path=DataContext.TestCommand}"/> <!--Updated binding works!-->
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Name="trayMainStack"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>
            </ScrollViewer>

            <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Test2" Command="{Binding TestCommand}"/> <!--This works-->
        </Grid>
    </tb:TaskbarIcon.TrayPopup>
</tb:TaskbarIcon>
```